# How do I design a css gradient to look like the attached Facebook Login screen

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am learning to use CSS. As a part of developing one of my apps, I have to display the information on the UI in the form of a card. I just can't seem to get the gradients right in css3. I don't want to use Photoshop to get this rich look. Any suggestions would help. Specially I could use help with the white highlight behind the Login Window

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-97uMEG8EH7k/Ti3-onpY-BI/AAAAAAAAA04/E7PMsEomKk4/s1600/110726_Facebook-in-iPad-Screen4.jpg]

Comment: Please share your current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to give you complete solution, but some hints how it should be achieved:

1. Use `radial gradient` to get background lighter in the center and darker near the edges. Because there will be a login window in the middle of the gradient, you'll get a *white highlight* effect!
2. User `linear gradient` as a background for login form window.
3. Set `border-radius` on login form window to get that window edges rounded.
4. Set `box-shadow` on login for window to a shadow under that window.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never received any emails from StackExchange, so I thought the question was dead. I am glad I checked today!!

Answer (score 1):

(As it is in the title I assume you only want to know how to create the gradient)

1) Pick colors using a colorpicker extension for the browser (like eyedropper for Chrome)

2) Use this cool CSS3 gradient generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

And, you're done :).